# Anicroc, nom masculin: d’où vient ce mot?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec

Au Québec on entend <strike>beaucoup plus</strike> (parfois) le nom masculin **anicroc** <strike>que le</strike> (en lieu et place du) nom féminin [**anicroche**](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/anicroche), de sens identique.

- Le voyage s’est déroulé sans **anicrocs**.
- Un petit **anicroc** nous oblige à remettre à demain la formation de premiers soins.

Au *Trésor de la langue française*, on spécifie une première attestation chez Rabelais en 1546, ***hanicroche***, dans l’introduction du *Tiers livre*, dans une longue série d’énumérations d’armes et outils de guerre et de combats. Le *Trésor* lui-même spécifie *« sorte d’arme en forme de* croc », mais le changement de forme de *croc* à *croche*, **s’il a eu lieu** dans un passé plus lointain, était déjà consommé chez Rabelais.

Cette époque nous ramène par ailleurs aux premiers jours de la Nouvelle-France. Difficile donc de ne pas tenir compte de cette attestation de Rabelais, et je suis par conséquent surpris de l’absence complète de la forme *anicroc* dans toutes les ressources linguistiques que j’ai consultées *(Le Petit Robert, Le Petit Larousse),* fussent-elles même très fortement québécoises *(Le Grand Druide des synonymes, le Glossaire du parler français au Canada)*.

D’où vient donc ce mot, <strike>omni</strike>présent chez les Québécois mais curieusement absent des outils de la langue ? Est-il d’apparition récente, ou au contraire une relique d’un passé sur lequel personne ne s’est vraiment encore penché ?

---

<sub>Suite à des commentaires de gens connaissant le Québec, comme je le connais aussi, je me suis rendu compte que cette manière de dire n’était peut-être pas si généralisée que ça. J’ai donc corrigé le tir afin de mieux représenter la réalité.</sub>

Comment: Tout ce que je peux dire, c'est que je n'ai jamais entendu ce mot (je suis Français). Par contre, « anicroche » est bien utilisé, plus particulièrement dans l'expression « sans anicroche(s) ».

Comment: @Toto Je supposais et continue de supposer que c’est en effet un régionalisme. Pourquoi existe-t-il, par contre? Je l’ignore complètement. Une conception locale d’un certain type d’euphonie? La variation de genre est-elle significative ou survenue par hasard? Y a-t-il un parallèle avec *croc* ou *accroc*? Le *O* arrondi semble-t-il dans la psychologie québécoise plus approprié que le *O* ouvert pour exprimer ce genre de concept? Ou alors, une raison d’usage historique suffit-elle à expliquer son existence?

Comment: J'ai été assez surpris de ne pas le connaître orthographié ou prononcé comme ça ! Le _Glossaire_ parle seulement d'une confusion entre le masculin et le féminin pour _anicroche_, comme en France dit-on en langage populaire, c'est le seul indice peut-être ; la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=anicroche&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=3772) a ça aussi mais c'est tout. En lisant votre question j'ai pensé à _sans accroc_ et au masculin _un anniversaire_, des trucs qui iraient dans le sens de l'emploi dont vous parlez parce que le cerveau lit plus vite que les yeux j'en sais rien. Merci !

Comment: @onvousaouï Ce mot fait partie de mon vocabulaire depuis mon enfance, et comme ma conjointe vient d’une région fort éloignée de la mienne et que sa famille l’utilise aussi, j’avais pensé qu’il était très commun un peu partout au Québec. Peut-être une généralisation hâtive de ma part.

Comment: Je vais poser la question autour de moi pour voir... Ce peut être aussi moi qui suit pas très _in_, qui sait...

Comment: J'ai passé 40 ans au Québec et n'ai jamais entendu _anicroc_. Dans quelle ville/région c'est utilisé ?

Comment: @Jeffrey Au moins en Abitibi et aux environs de la ville de Québec. Mais voir mon commentaire précédent: peut-être n’est-ce que le fruit d’un hasard improbable que ma conjointe et moi partagions cette façon de parler non-conforme...

Comment: @Feelew, je ne peux pas vraiment aider quant à l'origine mais je voulais te confirmer que c'est bien utilisé ici, je suis de la région de Montréal et c'est une expression que je connais, quoi que je ne l'utilise jamais.

Comment: J'ai consulté plusieurs dictionnaires du français (en ligne, hors ligne, "hard copies" et je n'arrive à trouver cde mot. En revenche anicroche existe bien.

Comment: @AlexDupuis Il me semblait bien que je ne fabulais pas complètement. Ce ne semble certes pas aussi courant que je le croyais, mais du moins cela semble maintenant avéré de plus d'une source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En dehors de ce fil et de faux positifs (erreurs de numérisation, noms propres, etc.), je ne trouve que deux occurrences de “anicroc” avec cette orthographe dans la littérature indexée par Google Books et deux autres sur le web :

- [La transcription d'une lettre de la fin du 18<sup>e</sup> siècle](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wkoLAAAAIAAJ&q=%22anicroc%22&dq=%22anicroc%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL443fh5_aAhVtSZoKHUR9BUA4ChDoAQhNMAY) qui utilise « qu'il y ait quelqu'anicroc ». Comme je ne peux pas voir le contexte, je ne suis pas sûr du sens, probablement « qu'il n'y ait pas de difficulté ».
- Une [transcription d'une lettre écrite en Île-de-France entre 1846 et 1982¹](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IAQiAQAAIAAJ&q=%22anicroc%22&dq=%22anicroc%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL443fh5_aAhVtSZoKHUR9BUA4ChDoAQhAMAQ), avec plusieurs fautes d'orthographe, qui utilise « nouvel anicroc » dans le sens de « nouveau problème ».
- Une [rédaction d'un élève de collège en Alsace](https://dncmalraux.blogspot.fr/2016/02/des-ecrivains-en-herbe.html) utilisant l'expression « sans anicroc ».
- Un [texte rédigé pour une association française](https://www.scribd.com/document/148703901/Souscrire-une-mutuelle-complementaire-pour-prevenir-des-accidents-de-la-vie) qui utilise « un anicroc » dans le sens d'« un accident ».

Vu la rareté du mot, mon hypothèse est qu'il s'agit d'une confusion entre les mots *accroc* et *anicroche* qui peuvent être synonymes (notamment dans l'expression « sans accroc/anicroche »). Comme le mot *anicroche* est plus rare mais a une sonorité qui ressemble un peu, il est naturel que la sonorité d'*accroc* déteigne dessus. Sur des centaines de millions de locuteurs, il peut bien y en avoir plusieurs qui ont fait cette assimilation indépendamment.

¹  <sub>Entre l'ouverture de la gare d'Épluches et la parution de l'ouvrage.</sub>

Comment: Merci de votre réponse. Vos exemples me suffisent pour penser qu'à l'oral, on trouverait encore bien plus d'utilisations diverses, et votre explication ne s'en trouverait que renforcée. Avec un témoignage de la région de Montréal confirmant que je n'étais pas en plein délire en posant cette question, je crois que ça suffira en attendant l'étude complète étayée d'une panoplie d'exemples.